# How to avoid multiple pages to open on quick taps of thumbnail on devices

Tags: ionic-framework, tap

I have an ionic application which has movies menu. On click of movies menu navigates to movies list in thumbnails. On click on any thumbnail navigates to its details page. But on quick taps opens multiple movie details pages equal to number of taps.

I tried adding a flag and a promise. But doesn't seem to work.

```
isTapped = false // by default

// Below code is executed
this.isTapped = true;
this.moviesFeedsService.getMovieDetails(asset.asset_id).subscribe
        ((msuMovieDetails) => {
          this.navCtrl.push(
            MediaDetailsPage,
            {
              headerDataTitle: this.headerData.title,
              movieDetails: msuMovieDetails,
              showEpisode: this.featureLayoutData.showEpisodes
            },
            navOptions
          ).then(() => {
            this.isTapped = false; // Reset flag
          });
        });
```

Expected : On tapping even multiple times page instance opened should be single

Actual : Multiple instances of page is opened on quick taps

Comment: seems your view pushing taking time, due to u waited for service response and then pushing . i suggest you to disable that movie item after first click and then wait for you code execution and moving , or first push the view and call this service in that deatils file and then display data

Comment: You can try adding a loader until you get the required information from the service.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading
Make sure to dismiss the loader in both success and error blocks.

Comment: I have disabled in template with the help of the flag isTapped but still could see the issue.